# Need to remove the s at the end of each word in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
const words = ["planes", "trains", "automobiles"];
```

Do I have to use the map method to remove the "s" from the end of each word?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? It sounds like you want someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function which will go through the array and remove the last character.

```js
const words = ["planes", "trains", "automobiles"];

const removeS = (array) => {
  var newArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(array[i].substring(0, array[i].length - 1));
  }
  console.log(newArray)
  return newArray;

}

removeS(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use map to iterate the array. Then, `.slice()` method to remove the last letter of each item.

```js
const array = ["planes", "trains", "automobiles"];

function removeLastLetter(array) {
  return array.map(el => el.slice(0, -1));
}

console.log(removeLastLetter(array));
```